# Python except Error handling doesn't display the text and error I tell it to, just crashes and displays weird lines?

Tags: python, csv, exception

Just some background info, this code has another python file which tests my code to see if it works correctly and handles all cases correctly as it's a university code/site.

I'm trying to write to a csv file and display this error if the code that tests it cant find the file:
"Error writing: the error"

My code and output can be shown in the image along with the expected output that the idle/lecturer expexts.

Any ideas on why my code displays the things it does and how I can get it to become the same as the expected output please?

```
import csv

def rememberInfo():

    name = input("What is your name?")
    print()
    age = input("How old are you?")
    print()
    course = input("What course are you on?")
    print()
    location = input("Where do you live?")
    print()

    try:
        with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
            employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',')
            employee_writer.writerow([name, age, course, location])
            line = name + "," + age + "," + course + "," + location
            print(line)
        employee_file.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error writing:", e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rememberInfo()
```

[image: Code And Output vs Expected Output]

Comment: Please paste the code in `text` form.

Comment: i have pasted it as text @Chirag

Comment: you're using a context manager (fancy name for `with open('xxx.csv', mode='w') as yyy:`), there's no need for `employee_file.close()` as file is closed at this point